# Can email be traced if sent from a phone with no sim card

Tags: privacy

I am using an old phone for web surfing only. If i sent an anonymous email (nothing illegal, just a flirty thing) can that email be traced back to the phone through my wifi?

Comment: What do you mean by "trace back to the phone"?

Comment: Who are you concern with tracing the email?  Random person? If your up against the NSA you have little to no protection.

Comment: As much as I hate pressing new users to give a threat model, I think it's necessary with this question. @D. J. Williams, can you [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/119405/edit) your question to include who you are trying to protect your anonymity from? The person receiving your email? Somebody else on the same wifi? The manufacturer of your router? Your ISP? The American NSA? The Canadian CSE? The answer is different for each of these because they have access to different kinds of routing information.

Answer (score 4):

**It doesn't make any difference with or without SIM card.** Briefly said, by sending email you will leave some traces. Some email services will send your IP address. (X-Originating-IP)

Here you can analyze email header, it's useful to understand what's happening in background.

https://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx

Comment: but if the email is a web-based service, then the IP will be of the service not the device

Comment: @schroeder, usually.  Some webmail services add the user's IP address to the headers, either as a `Received` header treating the browser as the originating client, or as an `X-Something-Or-Other` header.

Comment: So if I used my old smartphone to login to Starbucks WiFi, sent an email and threw away the device, would someone be able to "trace back to the phone" as OP asked or not? Can't see the answer here.

Comment: If the email is sent through an app on the phone, does the app send the device's IP? This answer needs some qualification. The OP should send an email to himself and read the headers to make sure, but there are too many unknowns to be making definite statements.

Comment: @techraf, Try this analyzer: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/